# How To Improve Performance of SwiftMailer DKIM Signer?

Tags: symfony, email

We send a Bible Daily Devotion to a large distribution each morning.  I believe the speed of our distribution process is limited by the DKIM Signer associated with Symfony/SwiftMailer. We send the same two part email (html & plain text) to each email address.  Each email is sent to only one email address with unique headers to assist with bounce processing.

Here is the process flow for each email we send:

- new \Swift_Message
- setSubject, setBody (html), addPart (plain text), addTextHeaders
- attachSigner for DKIM (Header/Relaxed, Body/Simple)
- send

How can I optimize this sequence to reduce processing time?  I know the DKIM processing is **expensive.** It would be great if the DKIM Body processing could be done only once as the Body of each email is the same.  The DKIM Header processing would need to be done for each email as the headers change from one email to the next.

What if I structured the code as follows:

- new \Swift Message
- setSubject, setBody (html), addPart (plain text)
- attachSigner for DKIM
- foreach email address

  - delete existing headers
  - addTextHeaders
  - send

I know this will improve performance some as less code is executed per email.  Is Swift smart enough to know that the content of the email Body did not change?  Is it smart enough to not perform DKIM Body calculations for each email?  If so, this would result is a Big performance improvement that has the potential to improve our email send rate.

Comment: Might be a better question for the Symfony Slack channel reachable through https://symfony.com/community

Comment: DKIM signs more than just the body, many headers are included in the signature. Your outgoing SMTP server should do the signing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that PHP is single threaded.  I divided the email distribution list in half and created two temporary files.  I then ran exec("... &") against each of the two files.  The "&" at the end of the command string starts the command and returns immediately.  The result is two tasks sending half of the email distribution concurrently. I could see the two tasks running at the same time using htop.

This resolved our performance limitation.